# omnet retransmitting the data packet at routing protocol

Tags: omnet++

I am working on a wireless routing protocol. I have created a Queue at every node. In this queue, every node kept packet which it already transmitted. If packet is not transmitted by nexthop then previous node will retransmit the packet after timeout. The problem is that when node is trying to retransmitt the packet by calling postRotingHook in handle function to retransmit then it is not doing anything. This postRoutingHook is created locally so it is not actually sending the packet. So how to connect this packet with network for retransmission?

Example: Suppose We have 3 nodes A, B and C. A is source, B is intermediate and C is destination. Node A sent a packet initially. Now node B will forward it to node C. At this time node A will overhear this packet and it will cancel the timer and delete this packet from its Queue. (in normal condition)

Suppose node B could not forward the packet because of some reason then node A should re-transmit the packet after time out. I am unable to achieve this functionality.

My programming scenario is:
I have modified GPSR protocol. Where header file have definition of these 5 INetfilterHooks methods. I didn't use any control packet e.g. request, response, beacon etc. I am directly dealing with data packet which contains some control information. I have implemented my logic in datagramPreRoutingHook() method (when data is received from lower layer) and  datagramLocalOutHook() method (when data is received from upper layer).

Source node (at network layer) receives packet from upper layer at IPv4.cc using handlePacketFromHL() ->datagramLocalOutHook(datagram, destIE, nextHopAddr) == INetfilter::IHook::ACCEPT) when it calls datagramLocalOutHook(datagram, destIE, nextHopAddr) then control goes to my routing protocol. It makes necessary changes, Adds source, destination address, creates options and keeps the packet in Queue (for retransmission by scheduling timer) then return ACCEP. Then control again goes to IPv4.cc.

After this process, if time out occurs at my protocol then I am unable to send packet to IPv4.cc. I called postRoutingHook to retransmit the packet then it simly return ACCEPT (as defined in header file) and does nothing. I have tried to call some methods of IPv4.cc by making object of IPv4 in my protocol but these methods are protected so I couldn't access these methods.
I tried with making some public methods of IPv4.cc but it is giving error at further stage.

I have tried to make the object of INetfilter::IHook for calling its postRoutingHook() but is also providing error as object of abstract class can not be created.